# Cursive behavior on blocked thread

Tags: multithreading, intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

Could someone please explain how the Cursive Clojure plugin in IntelliJ behaves when in the REPL it encounters a blocked thread.  It looks like instead of blocking the current thread it pushes its execution onto a new thread (judging by the enabled stop icon[image]) which, when clicked on, results in interruption of that thread and one can continue issuing commands in the original thread:

[image]

Would that be a correct assumption or am I missing something?  The behavior seems different from a regular Clojure REPL.  Thank you.